# how to allow form input information to be posted to a selected file?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

on a `<form>` you can make it post to a specific file.  I am wondering if there is a way to select multiple files to post, from the same input file.  my dream would be a dropdown menu that would allow you to pick the file which the inputs will be posted to. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two forms.

1. one with the dropdown and
2. other for actual work.

When user selects from the first dropdown the action of other form can be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

on your submit button click :

```
var e = document.getElementById("filetoPost");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.forms[0].action=strUser;
document.forms[0].submit();
```